# Reference a sheet name that doesn't yet exist but will be created from a variable in a cell. Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that automatically formats and copies a template and creates copies to go with the corresponding samples e.g. Cell H5 = Batch1, It creates a sheet Batch1.. Cell I5 = "Magenta", It creates a sheet called "Magenta".

I would now like to code a macro, that will copy data from a range of cells into one of these created sheets. However the sheets haven't been created yet.

Is there any way to use a cell reference to point to where the  where the data will be stored?

e.g. The sheet will be named whatever is in cell H5.. So use the cell reference to point to the worksheet instead of using an absolute sheet name?

Thanks for your help!

```
Sub CopyInfoSheetandInsert()

Dim rcell As Range
Dim Background As Worksheet
Set Background = Sheets("Formulation")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Template").Visible = True

For Each rcell In Range("D7:W7")

If rcell.Value <> "" And SheetExists(rcell.Value) = False Then

      Sheets("Template").Copy Before:=Sheets("COSHH")
      Sheets(Sheets("COSHH").Index - 1).Name = rcell.Value

End If

Next rcell

Sheets("Template").Visible = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub

Function SheetExists(SheetName) As Boolean
Dim sht As Worksheet

'Assume Failure
SheetExists = False

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If sht.Name = SheetName Then
        'Success
        SheetExists = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next sht

End Function
```

Comment: It should be simple to do but could you add the copying part of your code to the question so we can see how you're referencing sheets currently.

Comment: `Thisworkbook.Sheets(Thisworkbook.Sheets("Worksheet_Name").Range("H5").Value)`?

Comment: So I have the creation of the spreadsheets working fine, the code is above. But for example.. I have a series of data in D34:D38 that I want copied to the sheet name that is written in D7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the `Sheet.Copy` method (assuming you pass a `Before` of `After` argument, as you do), the active sheet will become the newly copied sheet. You can therefore simply use the `ActiveSheet` object to access the `Name` property.

See below for the adjusted code:

```
If rcell.Value <> "" And SheetExists(rcell.Value) = False Then

      Sheets("Template").Copy Before:=Sheets("COSHH")
      ActiveSheet.Name = rcell.Value
End If
```

**Update**

I'm not sure I fully understand your requirements but this might help:

If the sheet name occurs just once, then when the update is triggered your code could be:

```
Dim sheetName as String

sheetName = Worksheets("Data Entry").Range("D7").Value

...

Worksheets(sheetName)... 'this is the reference to your sheet.
```

If the name is going to change every time the user changes the value of D7, then you need to add a routine in the `Worksheet_Change` on the Data Entry worksheet. So you'd start by referencing the sheet at Module Level, like so:

```
Option Explicit
Private mCurSheet As Worksheet

Public Sub FirstCreationOfSheet()
    Set mCurSheet = Worksheets("whatever the name is")
End Sub
```

You'd then add a `Sub` in your module that changed the name:

```
Public Sub ChangeSheetName(newName As String)
    mCurSheet.Name = newName
End Sub
```

And then in your "Data Entry" code behind, you'd consume the Change event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Target.Cells
        If Not Intersect(Me.Range("D7"), cell) Is Nothing Then
            'Call the name change routine
            ChangeSheetName CStr(Me.Range("D7").Value)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry bear with me, I'm really struggling to explain this!

So that code will have been executed and the process has finished.

Comment: Sorry bear with me, I'm really struggling to explain this!

Step 1, above code will have been executed and the process has finished and created the sheets I need... e.g ("Sheet1")

A person will then use a worksheet "Data Entry" to enter some data.. which will then be copied into "Sheet1" from step 1.

What I need is to preemptively write the code for where the data entered on the "Data Entry" sheet will go..  

The sheet name will be specified in cell D7.

Comment: I know how to get the code to write to a worksheet, but it is referencing a sheet from a cell value.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Dim newSheetName As String
  newSheetName = ActiveSheet.Range("H5").Value
  Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = newSheetName
  Worksheets(newSheetName).Range("H6").Value = "Text for new sheet"
```

Above code picks sheetname from H5 in the variable newSheetName. Later when sheet is created, it places a text to the new sheet at cell H6

Comment: Not exactly what I required but I managed to solve it from your code.


    Sub UpdateInitials()
    '
    ' UpdateInitials Macro
    '
    
    
    Dim newSheetName As String
    newSheetName = ActiveSheet.Range("D7").Value
    
    Worksheets(newSheetName).Range("f7").Value = Worksheets("Formulation").Range("F50").Value
  
  
  
    End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure Jordan had the right answer for what you're after, applied to your scenario where the sheet to write to is in cell D7 of the worksheet "Data Entry":

```
Dim nuWS as Worksheet
Set nuWS = Thisworkbook.Sheets(Thisworkbook.Sheets("Data Entry").Ra‌​nge("D7").Value)
```

then you can copy from xyz worksheet and paste to the nuWS:

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets("Data Entry").[D34:D38].copy
nuWS.[A1].Paste
```

or just like

```
nuWS.[A1:A4].value = Thisworkbook.Sheet("Data Entry").[D34:D38].value
```